# CSS3 Media Query not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I have a test site located here:  69.16.224.73

The media queries are working fine on IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.  But they do not work on Safari (version 5.1.7).  Never seen this before, anybody have ideas?

Here is the two media queries I have on my site:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { }

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) { }
```

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: checked in FF, Chrome and Safari - nothing is changing in any of those..

Comment: Hi Zoltan, try it again, i was testing it and you probably checked when i was testing something.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 5):

do you have this below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

you can put this before end tag of your head

Comment: I added and still I don´t have it working too. What would be the correct media query syntax for Safari on windows?

Comment: try this meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1" />